# Establishing continuity of a function from a function relation.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

[image]

This question is from UGA paper of 2016(ISI).

Here I wanted to ask whether it is possible to establish continuity of the function. Once we do, my job will be done. But I am not able to use the functional relation to my advantage.Please help me here.

Comment: If $\lim_{x \to 0+}$ exists, then it has to be 0. The hard part is showing that it exists, but the wording of the question appears to imply that it exists.

Comment: Please do not use images to convey information not otherwise present in your post. [Here is the reason why.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/742).

Answer (score 1):

Let $\def \e {\varepsilon} \e > 0$. We will prove that $f(x) \to 0$ as $x \to 0$ by finding $\delta$ such that $\forall x \in [0, \delta],\, |f(x)| \leq \e$.

Let $n \in \mathbb N$ such that $3^{-n} \leq \e$.

Let $\delta = 2^{-n}$.

Then for any $x \in [0, \delta]$, we have $2^k x \leq \frac 1 2$ for $k \leq n-1$ and thus we can apply our formula repeatedly:
$$f(x) = \frac{f(2x)}{3} = \frac{f(4x)}{9} = ... = \frac{f(2^{n}x)}{3^n}$$

And since we know that $|f(y)| \leq 1$ for all $y$, we can conclude:
$$\forall x \in [0, \delta],\, |f(x)| \leq 3^{-n} \leq \e.$$

Hence $f(x) \to 0$ as $x \to 0$; or in other words, function $f$ is continuous at 0 and $f(0) = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Cheating:

If $\lim_{x \to 0+} f(x)$ is assumed to exist, then you don't need to show anything and you immediately have $\lim_{x \to 0+} f(x) = \lim_{x \to 0+} f(2x) = \lim_{x \to 0+} 3 f(x) = 3 \lim_{x \to 0+} f(x)$ and so the limit $\ell$ has to satisfy the equation $\ell = 3 \ell$, which means it must be 0.

The hard part is showing that $\lim_{x \to 0+} f(x)$ exists, but the wording of the question appears to imply that it exists.

Cheating even more:

Since this is a multiple-choice question, then from the wording of the question you can conclude:

> There exists a function $f$ with this property, and all functions $f$ with this property have the same $\lim_{x \to 0+} f(x)$.

So all you have to do is find one particular function $f$ that works, and take its limit.

I intuit that a simple $f$ that works is of the form $f(x) = x^k$ with $k$ such that $2^k = 3$. This gives $k = \frac{\log(3)}{\log(2)}$. Obviously $f$ is continuous and $\lim_{x \to 0+} f(x) = 0$.

Comment: but if I were to prove it rigorously, how could I do it?